# New RSS Feeds fields in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rss, jenkins-plugins

I want extra fields in the rss feed that jenkins currently provide.
I need build time field added to the rss feed. Is there a plugin or is it possible without any plugin?
Currently entries are like this.

```
<entry>
    <title>trunk-build #66 (stable)</title>
    <link type="text/html" href="xyz/66532/" rel="alternate"/>
    <published>2014-08-27T10:14:31Z</published>
    <updated>2014-08-27T10:14:31Z</updated>
    <content>trunk.ci.1143</content>
</entry>
```

I want to add duration of the build `<duration>15</duration>` to this entry.

Comment: Currently not possible in Jenkins core in any plugins to add fields to the feed. There is an [ancient bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-191) however.

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry to revive this but I am also interested in finding a way to expose information from builds to a php website, so either extend the rss or maybe there is a plugin that offers an api. I want to show the build properties - used to run the jobs.*

After a while I found out that Jenkins offers an [API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). I was able to achieve the result with the php implementation I found [here](https://github.com/jenkins-khan/jenkins-php-api).